# What does a 'complex displacement' of phonon mode mean?

Tags: terminology, complex-numbers, phonons

I'm trying to interpret the phonon mode output file from a phonopy/vasp calculation, and  [this](http://www-drfmc.cea.fr/L_Sim/V_Sim/sample.html) webpage talks about the 'complex displacement' of atoms in the system, and I'm not quite sure what it means...

> ### qpt:
>
> Define a phonon. The syntax for this keyword is qpt=[qx;qy;qz;en;...], where (qx;qy;qz) >stands for the q vector of the phonon and (en) stands for its energy. Then follow (6n) >values separated by ';' characters which represent the complex displacements for each >atom of the system (the three real parts followed by the three imaginary parts in a >cartesian basis set). A keyword line can by separated using a '\' character as last >character of the line. For instance:
>
> > metaData: qpt=[0.167;0.167;0.0000;-0.000039 \
> >
> > ; 0.542135; 0.542135; 0.626392; 0.020661; 0.020661; 0.028839 \
> >
> > ; 0.542506; 0.542506; 0.626965; -0.00492; -0.00492; -0.01065 \
> >
> > ; 0.544070; 0.544077; 0.623979; 0.008137; 0.007647; 0.009051 \
> >
> > ; 0.544077; 0.544070; 0.623979; 0.007647; 0.008137; 0.009051 \
> >
> > ; 0.545224; 0.546040; 0.629614; -0.05386; -0.04485; -0.05695 \
> >
> > ; 0.547737; 0.547868; 0.632119; 0.012470; 0.003422; 0.009170 \
> >
> > ]
>
> The energy value is currently not used in V_Sim. The units for the phonon coordinates >are given in box coordinates, including the two pi (i.e. a coordinates of 0.5 in x >direction corresponds to a periodicity of two boxes in that direction. Units of >displacements are not relevant since V_Sim will scale them to be visible (and thus much >amplified).

I tried to search for 'complex displacement phonon mode' etc. but didn't find anything, so I decided to ask other people for help...

Answer (score 1):

The complex displacement field usually refers to the temporal Fourier-transform of a time-harmonic displacement field.

For a single particle $u(t)$ with a scalar *time harmonic* displacement at angular frequency $\omega$ its Fourier transform along the temporal axis is

$$
\mathcal{F}(\omega) = \int_{- \infty}^{ \infty} u(t) \exp(- i \omega t) dt
$$

This reduces the displacements to a single complex value, or a 4D spatio-temporal displacement field to a 3D complex-valued displacement field. This is the form needed, for example, for most applications of the Helmholtz equation $\nabla u + k^2 u = 0$.